# Hibernate Template SaveOrUpdateALL primary key auto generation

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee

I am using the below method for saving a collection of objects to the Database.

```
public Collection save(Collection instances) {

        try {
            this.getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdateAll(instances);
            this.getHibernateTemplate().flush();


        } catch (RuntimeException re) {

            throw re;
        }
        return instances;
    }
```

The primary key for the instances is auto generated by the HibernateTemplate. After the JVM Startup, when this method is called for the first time, Hibernate runs the below query to get the Max primary key to used on the instances.

select max(Primary Key ID) from table_name

But the second time the method is executed, I don't see this query being executed.  Looks like hibernate stores this value somewhere in the session.

Now if the table is updated by a different process (lets say a stored procedure or SQL), all the subsequent calls to the above method fail with a ORA-00001: unique constraint (SCHEMANAME.PRIMARY_KEY_CONSTRAINT) violated exception.  If the JVM is restarted, Hibernate executes the max (Primary Key) generation query again, and everything works.

Can someone help on what I need to do, to make sure that the Primary Key auto generation query is run every time the method is executed (and not just the first time). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably chose the increment generator, which stored the max value in memory and then increments it. This strategy is not appropriate when you have multiple processes accessing the database (i.e. most of the time).

Choose another strategy (sequence, table, native, depending on your database capabilities and your preferences).

See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapping-declaration-id-generator for details

Comment: Where is this property set?  Is it in the Hibernate config properties.  Thanks for your help.  I haven't used Hibernate that extensively but the link you provided is helpful.

Comment: I found the id-generator in the Hibernate Table mapping configuration file. But changing it to anything other than increment is throwing an Hibernate Mapping exception, saying that the ID generator cannot be instantiated.
            <generator class="increment" />